# How to insert and inject a arraylist into any service or activity class using kodein dependency injection?

Tags: android, kotlin, kodein

Recently I have started to learn kodein dependency injection here I'm trying to load data into ArrayList and then inject that ArrayList into desired service or activity however I'm unable to do this and facing run time crashes any guidance will be appreciated.!

My Service Class:

```
class NotificationAccessibilityService() : AccessibilityService(),KodeinAware {
    override val kodein: Kodein = Kodein.lazy{
      import(AppModules().appModule(applicationContext))
    }
    val logger by instance<Logger>()
fun insertdata(){
//trying to insert data into arraylist
  logger.list = ArrayList()
  logger.list.add(mNodeInfo)
}
}
```

AppModules Class:

```
class AppModules()  {
    fun appModule(context:Context) = Kodein.Module{
        bind<Logger>() with  singleton { AndroidLogger() }
    }
}
```

Logger interface:

```
interface Logger {
    var list:ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo>
}
```

Logger Class:

```
class AndroidLogger() : Logger  {
    override var list: ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo>
        get() = TODO("not implemented")
        set(value) {}
}
```

In my Activity I'm extending kodeinaware and then trying to access that ArrayList from kodein however app is crashing:

```
class NormalCopy : AppCompatActivity(),KodeinAware {
    override val kodein: Kodein by closestKodein()

    val logger by kodein.instance<Logger>()

    var accesslist = logger.list

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, maybe I misunderstood you but it looks like you have to just remove `TODO` from your `Logger` implementation

```
class AndroidLogger() : Logger {
    override var list: ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo> = arrayListOf()
}
```